# How to copy a file to the memory in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, memory, copy-paste

I made a desktop app on Python and I need to give the user the ability to copy files shown on the app window , **not windows explorer** , so they can paste them where they desire.

Just like the *"right click and copy"* or *"ctrl+V"* in Windows.
I've only found a python function for copying a file from one dir to which uses shutil

```
shutil.copy(src, dst)
Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory, a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in the directory specified. Permission bits are copied. src and dst are path names given as strings.
```

But I want to save it on the memory so when the user clicks "paste" the file appears

How Can I achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for "python add to clipboard" at all? Your code is only related to actually copying from one source destination to another. Your question as it is now is more if an assignment than a question because you're asking us to research, code and test something you want to achieve. That is not what this community normally does for one another. Have a look at the FAQ or update your question with code showing some sort of effort in solving this that is slightly more relevant and closer to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes , I've searched but I only found how to copy plain text or Image type files to the clipboard.
Well I can't code something I dont know how to do , that's why I am asking

Answer (score 4):

The clipboard format that you need is [`CF_HDROP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776902#CF_HDROP). For example:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes
import pythoncom
import win32clipboard

class DROPFILES(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('pFiles', wintypes.DWORD),
                ('pt',     wintypes.POINT),
                ('fNC',    wintypes.BOOL),
                ('fWide',  wintypes.BOOL))

def clip_files(file_list):
    offset = ctypes.sizeof(DROPFILES)
    length = sum(len(p) + 1 for p in file_list) + 1
    size = offset + length * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_wchar)
    buf = (ctypes.c_char * size)()
    df = DROPFILES.from_buffer(buf)
    df.pFiles, df.fWide = offset, True
    for path in file_list:
        array_t = ctypes.c_wchar * (len(path) + 1)
        path_buf = array_t.from_buffer(buf, offset)
        path_buf.value = path
        offset += ctypes.sizeof(path_buf)
    stg = pythoncom.STGMEDIUM()    
    stg.set(pythoncom.TYMED_HGLOBAL, buf)
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    try:
        win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_HDROP,
                                        stg.data)
    finally:
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    clip_files([os.path.abspath(__file__)])
```